# Extract related data from 3 mysql tables and output as list items

Tags: php, menu, html-lists

I have a series of MySQL tables which are going to be used to create a menu system.

These are the tables: Section - SubCategory1 - SubCategory2

The data relates in the following ways:
Section 1 is the main headings in the menu.
SubCategory1 is the subcategories for the Section table
Subcategory1 is further refining of the Subcategory2 sections.

They contain the following:

```
SECTION
idSection, strSection, strSectionURL

SUBCATEGORY1
idSubCategory1, idSection, strSubCategory1

SUBCATEGORY2
idSubcategory2, idSubCategory1, strSubCategory2
```

As you can see, each has a reference to the table above it that is always the reference number for the section or subsection it belongs to.

I need the output as follows in a series of unordered lists so that I can format it into a menu system.

- SECTION
  - SUBCATEGORY1
    - SUBCATEGORY2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Phil

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm using PHP & MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from section");
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "<li>$row[strSection]</li>";
    $sql1 = mysql_query("select * from SUBCATEGORY1 where idSection ='$row[strSection]' ");
    echo "<ul>";
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
    {
        echo "<li>$row1[strSubCategory1]</li>";
        $sql2 = mysql_query("select * from SUBCATEGORY2 where strSubCategory1 ='$row[strSubCategory1]' ");
         echo "<ul>";
         while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
         {
              echo "<li>$row1[strSubCategory2]</li>";
         }
         echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

but i strongly recommend to use `Mysqli` OR `PDO` instead of `mysql`. This will print in list order as you specified.